# How to enable/use x3550 m4 onboard sata connector?

Tags: ibm-xseries

I have a X3550 M4 with a faulty M1115 raid card (tested faulty on a different machine), so I removed it. I noticed there is a mini-sas port on the motherboard with letters SATA 0-3 underneath. Also I see in the bios setup there is an option for switching the internal sata controller between AHCI and IDE mode. I assume this is the connector for the internal sata controller? I then used the cable to connect the backplane to this mini-sas connector and put a 2.5' sata drive in the caddy. However the sata drive does not show up in bios or anywhere. I cannot see it when I tried to install ubuntu server.

Has anyone gotten these sata ports to work?